# Advice about and improvements of this index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

**Short description:** I have an agenda with about 100.000 contacts.
I have an advanced search that give me the posibility to search contacts by: name, city, tag (some tag related with their town, eg: a guy from new your will get NYDude), faculty and I'm using some checkboxes to filter them by their gender.

Now, with 100.000 contacts my searches are a bit too slow so I decided to try some indexes. Keeping in mind that I don't have a great experience with indexes, your opinion would really help me. So:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts
        WHERE  (owner = '$user' AND 
               `city` LIKE '".$search."%' 
                OR `name` LIKE '".$search."%'
                OR `tag` LIKE '".$search."%'
                OR `faculty` LIKE '".$search."%')".$gender)
```

`$search` is the word passed from search box.
  `owner` is the person logged in. From my point of view, that should be the first element to be checked. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

My index looks like:

```
CREATE INDEX index_test ON contacts(owner, city, name, tag, faculty);
```

What do you think about and how do you suggest me to improve it?

I know that on indexes, the order of indexed columns is very important, but keeping in mind that my search don't follow any order rules (a user can search for town, name, faculty in any order), I can't control that.

Comment: How many contacts for a single owner? If not too many, maybe just index owner. Text-search index is tricky (as is OR-indexing).

Comment: Well, in practice I guess won't be to many, but on my test are about 100.000 contacts.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I think we need to see the actual query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a fulltext index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_test1 ON contacte(owner);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX index_test_all ON contacte(city,name,tag,faculty);
```

And your query:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts
    WHERE  (owner = '$user') AND 
           MATCH (`city`,`name`,`tag`, `faculty`) AGAINST ('".$search."')");
```

Read more about full text index in MySQL 5.6:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @Thilo I found a better solution, I just modify my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You link to the version5.0 documenation.  Prior to 5.6 fulltext is only supported with ISAM engine, which is a major restriction on its applicability.

Comment: @IvanCachicatari, this method seems to be nice, but I just can't test it with MySQL 5.6.15. I guess, there is a version incompatibility.

Comment: @SilenceIsGolden MySQL 5.6 have Innodb full text index

Answer (score 1):

All those `OR`s - are they really necessary?  Because there's no index which is going to help you with that query except this one:

```
CREATE INDEX index_contact_owner ON contacts(owner);
```

That will speed the retrieval of all the contacts owned by your user, which is the only constant term in your query.  The database can then filter the result set by Name, City, or whatever search criteria have actual values.

Why won't any other index help?  Because the OR clauses mean you have to search all the CITY, all the TAG, all the NAME, etc.  A compound index won't help you with TAG if you strike out on CITY.  Multiple individual indexes won't help, because the database can only use one of them.  Reading the whole table will be a more efficient option.

---

Please bear in mind that performance tuning is a mixture of good practice and experimentation.  Every situation is different.  Things will vary depending on data volumes and skew: how many Owners?  range of contacts?  how often does the user specify city?  And so on.  So although we can give you advice, you really need to try out different approaches and see what works best for you.

Comment: a full-text-search index might help.

Comment: That's what I was afraid too. Another things what I was thinking was to create a separate index for city, tag, faculty and name and to let QO (I hope that have the same name in Mysql too) to decide what index needs to be used. What do you think about that? And those `OR`s are necessary because I really want that the search to be a bit more `advanced` as a usual search.